# What kind of curve (or model) should I fit to my percentage data?

Tags: regression, modeling, curve-fitting, percentage

I am trying to create a figure which shows the relationship between viral copies and genome coverage (GCC). This is what my data looks like:

[image: Viral load vs GCC]

At first, I just plotted a linear regression but my supervisors told me that was incorrect, and to try a sigmoidal curve. So I did this using geom_smooth:

```
library(scales)
ggplot(scatter_plot_new, aes(x = Copies_per_uL, y = Genome_cov, colour = Virus)) +
    geom_point() +
    scale_x_continuous(trans = log10_trans(), breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x), labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x))) +
        geom_smooth(method = "gam", formula = y ~ s(x), se = FALSE, size = 1) +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(legend.position = 'top', legend.text = element_text(size = 10), legend.title = element_text(size = 12), axis.text = element_text(size = 10), axis.title = element_text(size=12), axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin (r = 10)), axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = 10))) +
    labs(x = "Virus copies/µL", y = "GCC (%)") +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(25,50,75,100))
```

[image: Viral load vs GCC - geom_smooth]

However, my supervisors say this is incorrect too because the curves make it look like GCC can go over 100%, which it can't.

My question is: what is the best way to show the relationship between virus copies and GCC? I want to make it clear that A) low virus copies = low GCC, and that B) after a certain amount of virus copies the GCC plateaus.

I've researched a lot of different methods - GAM, LOESS, logistic, piecewise - but I don't know how to tell what is the best method for my data.

EDIT: this is the data:

```
>print(scatter_plot_new)  
Subsample   Virus   Genome_cov  Copies_per_uL
1   S1.1_RRAV   RRAV    100 92500
2   S1.2_RRAV   RRAV    100 95900
3   S1.3_RRAV   RRAV    100 92900
4   S2.1_RRAV   RRAV    100 4049.54
5   S2.2_RRAV   RRAV    96.9935 3809
6   S2.3_RRAV   RRAV    94.5054 3695.06
7   S3.1_RRAV   RRAV    3.7235  86.37
8   S3.2_RRAV   RRAV    11.8186 84.2
9   S3.3_RRAV   RRAV    11.0929 95.2
10  S4.1_RRAV   RRAV    0   2.12
11  S4.2_RRAV   RRAV    5.0799  2.71
12  S4.3_RRAV   RRAV    0   2.39
13  S5.1_RRAV   RRAV    4.9503  0.16
14  S5.2_RRAV   RRAV    0   0.08
15  S5.3_RRAV   RRAV    4.4147  0.08
16  S1.1_UMAV   UMAV    5.7666  1.38
17  S1.2_UMAV   UMAV    26.0379 1.72
18  S1.3_UMAV   UMAV    7.4128  2.52
19  S2.1_UMAV   UMAV    21.172  31.06
20  S2.2_UMAV   UMAV    16.1663 29.87
21  S2.3_UMAV   UMAV    9.121   32.82
22  S3.1_UMAV   UMAV    92.903  627.24
23  S3.2_UMAV   UMAV    83.0314 615.36
24  S3.3_UMAV   UMAV    90.3458 632.67
25  S4.1_UMAV   UMAV    98.6696 11180
26  S4.2_UMAV   UMAV    98.8405 12720
27  S4.3_UMAV   UMAV    98.7939 8680
28  S5.1_UMAV   UMAV    98.6489 318200
29  S5.2_UMAV   UMAV    99.1303 346100
30  S5.3_UMAV   UMAV    98.8767 345100
```

Comment: Make use of the "G" in "GAM". I don't know enough about genome coverage (appears to be a percentage?) to recommend a family but you probably want a logit link.

Comment: Seems like a logistic regression would be best, since this is bounded between 0 and 100%.

Comment: Try (2) piece-wise (linear) model.

Comment: try adding `method.args=list(family=quasibinomial))` in the arguments to `geom_smooth()` in your original ggplot code.

Comment: @BenBolker yes, this removed the extended arch on the curves - thank you!

Comment: PS I would encourage you *not* to suppress standard errors with `se=FALSE`.  Always nice to show people how large the uncertainty actually is ...

Comment: After your edit to include the actual data, I have updated my answer with a plot of the 3-parameter logistic type equation using your updated data.

Comment: I agree with your supervisor, fitting a sigmoidal curve would be a good choice.  The two lines you show in your second plot seem not to be sigmoidal?   Have a look on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) .

Comment: You don't have enough data points in the transition region to claim with any authority that there's a smooth curve.  I could just as easily fit a Heaviside function to the points you are showing us.

Comment: 4 years later I have a followup question. (This is the first time I come across this thread.) 
I notice the observations come in clusters of three with about the same x. Are these data points independent measurements? Or -- and I think this is more likely -- are they replicate measurements taken during the same lab experiment? All the answers so far assume the data consists of 30 independent data points, not 10 independent experiments (5 for each virus) with three repeat measurements each.

Comment: @dipetkov each data point is an independent measurement as there were three technical replicate samples per viral spike level, so each of these were measured separately, not repeatedly (I hope I interpreted your question correctly). I ended up publishing this work: https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-019-55741-3 Figure 1 illustrates the experiment design, which might help in understanding what the data actually represent and how it was collected.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding and congratulations on publishing your work in Nat Sci Reports! I took a look at the paper and I think the interesting structure in the data (what I called "clusters of three") is explained by the design of the experiment and that there were 15 subsamples analyzed. I admit though that I didn't understand lots of the science as I have no knowledge of sequencing. Again, thanks for sharing the extra information!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

another way to go about this would be to use a Bayesian formulation, it can be a bit heavy going to start with but it tends to make it much easier to express specifics of your problem as well as getting better ideas of where the "uncertainty" is

[Stan](https://mc-stan.org) is a Monte Carlo sampler with a relatively easy to use programmatic interface, libraries are available for [R and others](https://mc-stan.org/users/interfaces/) but I'm using Python here

we use a sigmoid like everybody else: it has biochemical motivations as well as being mathematically very convenient to work with.  a nice parameterization for this task is:

```py
import numpy as np

def sigfn(x, alpha, beta):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-(x - alpha) * beta))
```

where `alpha` defines the midpoint of the sigmoid curve (i.e. where it crosses 50%) and `beta` defines the slope, values nearer zero are flatter

to show what this looks like, we can pull in your data and plot it with:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_table('raw_data.txt', delim_whitespace=True)
df.columns = ['subsample', 'virus', 'coverage', 'copies']
df.coverage /= 100

x = np.logspace(-1, 6, 201)
plt.semilogx(x, sigfn(np.log(x), 5.5, 3), label='sigfn', color='C2')

sns.scatterplot(df.copies, df.coverage, hue=df.virus, edgecolor='none')
```

where `raw_data.txt` contains the data you gave and I transformed the coverage to something more useful.  the coefficients 5.5 and 3 look nice and give a plot very much like the other answers:

[image: plot data and manual fit]

to "fit" this function using Stan we need to define our model using its own language that's a mix between R and C++.  a simple model would be something like:

```
data {
    int<lower=1> N;  // number of rows
    vector[N] log_copies;
    vector<lower=0,upper=1>[N] coverage;
}
parameters {
    real alpha;
    real beta;
    real<lower=0> sigma;
}
model {
    vector[N] mu;
    mu = 1 ./ (1 + exp(-(log_copies - alpha) * beta));

    sigma ~ cauchy(0, 0.1);
    alpha ~ normal(0, 5);
    beta ~ normal(0, 5);

    coverage ~ normal(mu, sigma);
}
```

which hopefully reads OK.  we have a `data` block that defines the data we expect when we sample the model, `parameters` define the things that are sampled, and `model` defines the likelihood function.  You tell Stan to "compile" the model, which takes a while, and then you can sample from it with some data. for example:

```py
import pystan

model = pystan.StanModel(model_code=code)
model.sampling(data=dict(
    N=len(df),
    log_copies=np.log(df.copies),
    coverage=df.coverage,
), iter=10000, chains=4, thin=10)

import arviz
arviz.plot_trace(fit)
```

`arviz` makes nice diagnostic plots easy, while printing the fit gives you a nice R-style parameter summary:

```
4 chains, each with iter=10000; warmup=5000; thin=10; 
post-warmup draws per chain=500, total post-warmup draws=2000.

        mean se_mean     sd   2.5%    25%    50%    75%  97.5%  n_eff   Rhat
alpha   5.51  6.0e-3   0.26   4.96   5.36   5.49   5.64   6.12   1849    1.0
beta    2.89    0.04   1.71   1.55   1.98   2.32   2.95   8.08   1698    1.0
sigma   0.08  2.7e-4   0.01   0.06   0.07   0.08   0.09    0.1   1790    1.0
lp__   57.12    0.04   1.76   52.9   56.1  57.58  58.51  59.19   1647    1.0
```

the large standard deviation on `beta` says that the data really doesn't provide much information about this parameter.  also some of the answers giving 10+ significant digits in their model fits are overstating things somewhat

because some answers noted that each virus might need its own parameters I extended the model to allow `alpha` and `beta` to vary by "Virus".  it all gets a bit fiddly, but the two viruses almost certainly have different `alpha` values (i.e. you need more copies/μL of RRAV for the same coverage) and a plot showing this is:

[image: plot of data and MC samples]

the data is the same as before, but I've drawn a curve for 40 samples of the posterior.  `UMAV` seems relatively well determined, while `RRAV` could follow the same slope and need a higher copy count, or have a steeper slope and a similar copy count.  most of the posterior mass is on needing a higher copy count, but this uncertainty might explain some of the differences in other answers finding different things

I mostly used answering this as an exercise to improve my knowledge of Stan, and I've put a Jupyter notebook of this [here](https://github.com/smason/stackoverflow/blob/master/stan%20fit%20viral%20coverage.ipynb) in case anyone is interested/wants to replicate this.

Answer (score 17):

(Edited taking into account comments below. Thanks to @BenBolker & @WeiwenNg for helpful input.)

Fit a fractional logistic regression to the data. It is well suited to percentage data that is bounded between 0 and 100% and is well-justified theoretically in many areas of biology.

Note that you might have to divide all values by 100 to fit it, since programs frequently expect the data to range between 0 and 1. And as Ben Bolker recommends, to address possible problems caused by the binomial distribution's strict assumptions regarding variance, use a quasibinomial distribution instead.

I've made some assumptions based on your code, such as that there are 2 viruses you are interested in and they may show different patterns (i.e. there may be an interaction between virus type and number of copies).

First, the model fit:

```
dat <- read.csv('Book1.csv')
dat$logcopies <- log10(dat$Copies_per_uL)
dat$Genome_cov_norm <- dat$Genome_cov/100

fit <- glm(Genome_cov_norm ~ logcopies * Virus, data = dat, family = quasibinomial())
summary(fit)


Call:
glm(formula = Genome_cov_norm ~ logcopies * Virus, family = quasibinomial(), 
    data = dat)

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-0.55073  -0.13362   0.07825   0.20362   0.70086  

Coefficients:
                    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)          -5.9702     2.8857  -2.069   0.0486 *
logcopies             2.3262     1.0961   2.122   0.0435 *
VirusUMAV             2.6147     3.3049   0.791   0.4360  
logcopies:VirusUMAV  -0.6028     1.3173  -0.458   0.6510  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for quasibinomial family taken to be 0.6934319)

    Null deviance: 30.4473  on 29  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  2.7033  on 26  degrees of freedom
```

If you trust the p-values, the output does not suggest that the two viruses differ meaningfully. This is in contrast to @NickCox's results below, though we used different methods. I'd not be very confident either way with 30 data points.

Second, the plotting:

<s>It's not hard to code up a way to visualize the output yourself, but there appears to be a ggPredict package that will do most of the work for you (can't vouch for it, I haven't tried it myself). The code will look something like:</s>

```
library(ggiraphExtra)
ggPredict(fit) + theme_bw(base_size = 20) + geom_line(size = 2)
```

Update: I no longer recommend the code or the ggPredict function more generally. After trying it out I found that the plotted points don't exactly reflect the input data but instead are changed for some bizarre reason (some of the plotted points were above 1 and below 0). So I recommend coding it up yourself, though that is more work.

Comment: I endorse this answer, but I'd like to make a point of clarification: I'd call this fractional logistic regression. I think this term would be more widely recognized. When most people hear "logistic regression", I bet they think of a 0/1 dependent variable. One good Stackexchange answer dealing with this nomenclature is here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/216122/what-is-the-difference-between-logistic-regression-and-fractional-response-regre

Comment: @WeiwenNg Interesting, I wasn't aware of this distinction.

Comment: @mkt I tried this but got this error: "Error in eval(family$initialize) : y values must be 0 <= y <= 1" I assume this has to do with my data - I have added the data to my original question. Does this type of data change the kind of model I can use?

Comment: @teaelleceecee You  evidently have to divide the coverage by 100 first.

Comment: @teaelleceecee NickCox is right. I've edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @NickCox thank you - I have now divided the coverage by 100, got this warning message: "In eval(family$initialize) : non-integer #successes in a binomial glm!" Nevertheless, fit was created, so I ran "ggPredict(fit, se = TRUE)" but that gave the error message: "Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'Copies_per_uL' not found". I realise this is because the column is now called "log10(Copies_per_uL)" but how do I get around this? Apologies, this is the first analysis I have done in R so I'm a bit lost...

Comment: I am not a routine R user to advise. In any case, the details of how to do this in R are off-topic here. Nevertheless, your problem may be trivial and someone may  advise. Alternatively, switch to Stata, as in my answer.

Comment: @teaelleceecee A quick fix for that is to log transform the column before you feed it into the glm formula. i.e. don't use log10() inside glm(), but do that in a separate line beforehand.

Comment: use `family=quasibinomial()` to avoid the warning (and the underlying problems with too-strict variance assumptions). Take @mkt's advice on the other problem.

Comment: @BenBolker brilliant - that indeed worked to remove the warning and mkt's advice got ggPredict working. Thank you!

Comment: This may work, but I would like to warn folks that you should have a premise **prior** to fitting a function that your data in fact **should** follow that function.  Otherwise you are pretty much shooting at random when you pick a fitting function, and you may be fooled by the results.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft We hear the sermon but are sinners outside the service. What prior premise led you to suggest a Heaviside function in other comments? The biology here doesn't resemble transition at a sharp threshold. The fact of research here as I understand is that formal theory is weaker than the data. I agree: if people think that a step function makes sense, they should fit one.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I agree with your general point. Though I don't know much about this specific project, I'm somewhat familiar with this general area of research. The logistic is frequently used and has good theoretical justification in the cases I've encoutered. I've yet to come across the use of step functions in the field, though good uses might well exist.

Comment: @NickCox  Fair points indeed.

Comment: I would argue that GAM + logit link + quasibinomial variance is a pretty flexible model, if the OP wants to use that instead of assuming exact linearity on the log scale ... (although that does assume smoothness rather than steppiness ...)

Answer (score 14):

This isn't a different answer from @mkt but  graphs in particular won't fit into a comment. I first fit a logistic curve in Stata (after logging the predictor) to all data and get this graph

[image]

An equation is

100 `invlogit`(-4.192654 + 1.880951 `log10`(`Copies`))

Now I fit curves separately for each virus in the simplest scenario of virus defining an indicator variable. Here for the record is a Stata script:

```
clear 
input id str9 Subsample   str4 Virus   Genome_cov  Copies_per_uL
1   S1.1_RRAV   RRAV    100 92500
2   S1.2_RRAV   RRAV    100 95900
3   S1.3_RRAV   RRAV    100 92900
4   S2.1_RRAV   RRAV    100 4049.54
5   S2.2_RRAV   RRAV    96.9935 3809
6   S2.3_RRAV   RRAV    94.5054 3695.06
7   S3.1_RRAV   RRAV    3.7235  86.37
8   S3.2_RRAV   RRAV    11.8186 84.2
9   S3.3_RRAV   RRAV    11.0929 95.2
10  S4.1_RRAV   RRAV    0   2.12
11  S4.2_RRAV   RRAV    5.0799  2.71
12  S4.3_RRAV   RRAV    0   2.39
13  S5.1_RRAV   RRAV    4.9503  0.16
14  S5.2_RRAV   RRAV    0   0.08
15  S5.3_RRAV   RRAV    4.4147  0.08
16  S1.1_UMAV   UMAV    5.7666  1.38
17  S1.2_UMAV   UMAV    26.0379 1.72
18  S1.3_UMAV   UMAV    7.4128  2.52
19  S2.1_UMAV   UMAV    21.172  31.06
20  S2.2_UMAV   UMAV    16.1663 29.87
21  S2.3_UMAV   UMAV    9.121   32.82
22  S3.1_UMAV   UMAV    92.903  627.24
23  S3.2_UMAV   UMAV    83.0314 615.36
24  S3.3_UMAV   UMAV    90.3458 632.67
25  S4.1_UMAV   UMAV    98.6696 11180
26  S4.2_UMAV   UMAV    98.8405 12720
27  S4.3_UMAV   UMAV    98.7939 8680
28  S5.1_UMAV   UMAV    98.6489 318200
29  S5.2_UMAV   UMAV    99.1303 346100
30  S5.3_UMAV   UMAV    98.8767 345100
end 

gen log10Copies = log10(Copies)
gen Genome_cov_pr = Genome_cov / 100
encode Virus, gen(virus)
set seed 2803 
fracreg logit Genome_cov_pr log10Copies i.virus, vce(bootstrap, reps(10000)) 

twoway function invlogit(-5.055519 + 1.961538 * x), lc(orange) ra(log10Copies)      ///
|| function invlogit(-5.055519 + 1.233273 + 1.961538 * x), ra(log10Copies) lc(blue) ///
|| scatter Genome_cov_pr log10Copies if Virus == "RRAV", mc(orange) ms(Oh)          ///
|| scatter Genome_cov_pr log10Copies if Virus == "UMAV", mc(blue) ms(+)             ///
legend(order(4 "UMAV" 3 "RRAV") pos(11) col(1) ring(0))                             ///
xla(-1 "0.1" 0 "1" 1 "10" 2 "100" 3 "10{sup:3}" 4 "10{sup:4}" 5 "10{sup:5}")        ///
yla(0 .25 "25" .5 "50" .75 "75" 1 "100", ang(h))                                    ///
ytitle(Genome coverage (%)) xtitle(Genome copies / {&mu}L) scheme(s1color)
```

This is pushing hard on a tiny dataset but the P-value for virus looks supportive of fitting two curves jointly.

```
Fractional logistic regression                  Number of obs     =         30
                                                Replications      =     10,000
                                                Wald chi2(2)      =      48.14
                                                Prob > chi2       =     0.0000
Log pseudolikelihood = -6.9603063               Pseudo R2         =     0.6646

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
              |   Observed   Bootstrap                         Normal-based
Genome_cov_pr |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
  log10Copies |   1.961538   .2893965     6.78   0.000     1.394331    2.528745
              |
        virus |
        UMAV  |   1.233273   .5557609     2.22   0.026     .1440018    2.322544
        _cons |  -5.055519   .8971009    -5.64   0.000    -6.813805   -3.297234
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I extracted the data from your scatterplot, and my equation search turned up a 3-parameter logistic type equation as a good candidate: "y = a / (1.0 + b * exp(-1.0 * c * x))", where "x" is the log base 10 per your plot. The fitted parameters were a = 9.0005947126706630E+01, b = 1.2831794858584102E+07, and c = 6.6483431489473155E+00 for my extracted data, a fit of the (log 10 x) original data should yield similar results if you re-fit the original data using my values as initial parameter estimates. My parameter values are yielding R-squared = 0.983 and RMSE = 5.625 on the extracted data.

[image: plot]

EDIT: Now that the question has been edited to include the actual data, here is a plot using the above 3-parameter equation and initial parameter estimates.

[image: plot2]

Comment: There seems to have been an error in your data extraction: you have a bunch of negative percentage values. Also, your maximum values are at about 90% instead of 100% as in the original plot. You may have everything offset by about 10% for some reason.

Comment: Meh - this is semi-manually  extracted data, the original data is required. This is usually sufficient for equation searches, and of course not for final results - which is why I said to use my extract-o-fit parameter values as initial parameter estimates on the original data.

Comment: Please note that as the actual data has now been added to the post, I have updated this answer using the updated data.

Comment: Just to reiterate:  application of, e.g., a Heaviside function, may yield similar error values.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft because the full data set has now been added to the question, there is no need for conjecture - is now possible to determine this directly. For comparative purposes, please do so.

Comment: @JamesPhillips I will attempt to do so (Heaviside -->  errorbars or equivalent)

Comment: How did  you do your **equation search**?

Answer (score 4):

Try [sigmoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function#Examples) function. There are many formulations of this shape including a logistic curve. Hyperbolic tangent is another popular choice.

Given the plots, I can't rule out a simple step function either. I'm afraid you will not be able to differentiate between a step function and any number of sigmoid specifications. You don't have any observations where your percentage is in 50% range, so the simple step formulation can be the most parsimoinous choice that performs no worse than more complex models

Comment: It's worth noting the hyperbolic tangent is closely related to the sigmoid function, viz. $\sigma(x)=\frac12\left(1+\tanh\frac{x}{2}\right)$.

Comment: @J.G. "sigmoid" is a generic term for an S-curve, as far as I'm concerned, but you're right to point to a link between two specifications of a sigmoid

Answer (score 4):

Here are the 4PL (4 parameter logistic) fits, both constrained and unconstrained, with the equation as per C.A. Holstein, M. Griffin, J. Hong, P.D. Sampson, “Statistical Method for Determining and Comparing Limits of Detection of Bioassays”, *Anal. Chem.* **87** (2015) 9795-9801. The 4PL equation is shown in both figures and the parameter meanings are as follows: a = lower asymptote, b = slope factor, c = inflection point, and d = upper asymptote.

Figure 1 constrains a to equal 0% and d to equal 100%:

[image: Fig. 1 Constrained a & d]

Figure 2 has no constraints on the 4 parameters in the 4PL equation:

[image: Fig. 2 No constraints]

This was fun, I make no pretence of knowing anything biological and it will be interesting to see how it all settles out!

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful. Just wondering, did you do this in MATLAB with the fit function?

Comment: I used Igor Pro with the user-defined user function shown in the figures. I have used Igor Pro and its predecessor (Igor) since 1988, but lots of other programs can do the curve fitting, e.g., Origin Pro and the very inexpensive Kaleidagraph. And it appears that you have R and (possibly?) access to Matlab, neither of which I know anything about except that they are extremely capable. Best of success with this and I hope you get good news the next time you discuss things with the supervisors! Also, thanks for posting the data!

Answer (score 4):

Since I had to open my big mouth about Heaviside, here's the results.  I set the transition point to log10(viruscopies) = 2.5 .  Then I calculated the standard deviations of the two halves of the data set -- that is, the Heaviside is assuming the data on either side has all derivatives = 0 .

RH side std dev = 4.76
LH side std dev = 7.72

Since it turns out there's 15 samples in each batch, the overall std dev is the mean, or 6.24 .

Assuming the "RMSE" quoted in other answers is "RMS error" overall,  the Heaviside function would appear to do at least as well as, if not better than, most of the "Z-curve" (borrowed from photographic response nomenclature) fits here.

### edit

Useless graph, but requested in comments:

[image: Heaviside curve fit]

Comment: Woukd you please post a model and scatterplot similarly to what was done in the other answers? I am most curious to see these results and compare. Please also add RMSE and R-squared values for comparison. I personally have never use the Heaviside function and find this very interesting.

Comment: @JamesPhillips  There really isn't anything to show  - obviously the scatterplot is the same; all I did was manually select the transition point and take the raw mean of each set of points (left-hand and right-hand).  I'm not  sure $R^2$ has much meaning here.

Comment: My meaning was to make a plot similar to those made in the other answers, for the purpose of direct comparison to those answers.

Comment: @JamesPhillips you have two wishes left.  Choose wisely :-)

Comment: Thank you for the plot. I observe that in all plots in other answers, the plotted equation follows the curved shape of the data at the top right - your does not, as is the nature of the Heaviside function. This visually appears to contradict your assertion that the Heaviside function would do as well as the equations posted in the other answers - which is why I had previously requested the RMSE and R-squared values, I suspected that the Heaviside function would not follow the shape of the data in this region and might yield worse values for those fit statistics.