# What do I do when my model prediction exceeds the limit of 100%?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, data-visualization, poisson-regression, effects

I have plotted the effects of a model `glm( A ~ B, family=poisson, data=data)` both with the `sjplot` R package and with the `effects` package. However, my `A` variable is a percentage (min=0, max=100) and the effect plot shows `A` values higher than 100. What should I do?

Comment: I've changed your title because it seems like the problem is not your plot, but the underlying model. Please check the edit to see if it captures your meaning.

Comment: A Poisson regression is suitable when the outcome is a count. In your case, the outcome `A` is a percentage. In that case, I'd recommend using logistic regression or beta regression.

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/418584/121522

Answer (score 4):

If the prediction limits or confidence intervals exceed some limit beyond which predictions/inference become unphysical, then your model is misspecified.

The most straightforward example of this is using linear regression to perform prediction of a continuous covariate's affect on a binary outcome.  Eventually, the model will predict something above/below 1/0.

The poisson's mean is supported on the positive reals, and so if your outcome is bounded to the unit interval, you may consider a logistic regression or a beta regression.  To say more, we would need to know what you are modelling and perhaps see some data.

Comment: thank you so much to @mkt and DemetriPananos