# Random effects for ordinal logistic regression?

Tags: random-effects-model, continuous-data, ordered-logit, polr

I am relatively new to R. I am currently using R studio to run an ordinal logistic regression for some research. Initially I just ran the ordinal logistic regression using R's polr function, I didn't manipulate the variables at all.

My advisor later said that I need to change this code so that I have continuous effects of my temperature variable and random effects of individuals in my study.   I think that naturally the `polr` function uses continuous effects, correct me if I'm wrong? And now I need to make one of my variables have random effects. The reason I need random effects is because I have 5 individuals in my study that each have several observations. Essentially I have repeated observations on the same individual. He said to use the `clmm` function? But I'm not sure how to go about doing that or how to target my variable. Please let me know.

Comment: Could you provide a little bit more background on the study design, how the data were collected, and what the first few rows of your data look like? That would help provide an answer.

Comment: Maybe answered here:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/238581/how-to-use-ordinal-logistic-regression-with-random-effects