# Replicating a study with a discrete dependent variable in linear mixed effects model (1-4 scores)

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, assumptions, discrete-data, dependent-variable

As the title says, I want to replicate a study that runs linear mixed effects models with a dependent variable that is discrete, with scores from 1 to 4. So, I have two main questions about that.

1 ) When is it allowed to have discrete dependent variables ? Do you have any references about it ?

2 ) Is it even possible to check assumptions in a model with a discrete DV ? (In R, if that matters.) I'm confused.

Thank you in advance,

Lara

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use ordinal logistic regression with random effects?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/238581/how-to-use-ordinal-logistic-regression-with-random-effects) To maintain the ordering among the dependent-variable levels, you need an ordinal regression. If your discrete outcomes weren't ordered, you could do a multinomial regression. The linked question should point the way to what you need.

Comment: A search for `ordinal logistic regression` on this site provides over 1000 results for further study.