# Regression Model when dependent variable is ranking

Tags: regression, modeling

I am trying to construct a regression model which the value would be the ranking of the products. There is 9 total in ranks, where 1 means the top 1.I am wondering which model should I use.

Thank you so much!

Comment: what are your independent variables and pl. state your objective ?

Comment: Which value is the ranking?  Is this a dependent or independent variable?

Comment: Have a look at this question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/93454/how-do-i-run-ordinal-logistic-regression-analysis-in-r-with-both-numerical-cat also, the [ordinal](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ordinal/ordinal.pdf) package in R https://www.r-project.org/conferences/useR-2011/TalkSlides/Contributed/17Aug_1600_FocusIV_4-Regression_2-Haubo.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A logistic regression model is suited for this scenario.

This model is one which has an ordinal variable (your ranking scale for the products) as opposed to an interval variable where intervals between each value are equal in distance.

If you are using R, you can use the **glm** model in order to run this regression.

Assuming y = product ranking, X1 = Independent Variable 1, X2 = Independent Variable 2:

`regression<-glm(y ~ X1 + X2, data=yourdata)` is the command you would use in R to run this regression.

A few points to note with this model:

- According to Studenmund (2010), a logistic regression model will generally show more accuracy in terms of significance when the number of observations are 500 or above. This is because a lower degree of variation in the dependent variable may not capture the true significance of the correlation with a lower number of observations.
- The coefficients are interpreted as odds ratios - not in the same way as in a standard OLS regression model. As an example, this [page by UCLA](http://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stata/faq/how-do-i-interpret-odds-ratios-in-logistic-regression/) demonstrates that an odds ratio can be calculated by raising e to the power of the coefficient in your regression model.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This way he/she will lose all information relative to ordering of the output rank. it's much better to use ordinal logistic regression: http://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/ordinal-logistic-regression/

Comment: Correct, the ordering is important. The above example being more of a guide to how the logistic regression could be set up more generally.

Comment: Aside from the above comments about ordinal logistic regression being the right model, to make the above model logistic, don't you need to add `family=binomial(link=logit)` to the call to glm?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ordinal logistic model.