# Relationship between two categorical variable

Tags: regression, logistic, categorical-data, ordinal-data, ordered-logit

I'm trying to check a relationship between two variable. one with three levels and other is with 7 levels.
one variable is `overall_sentiment with (Positive, Negative, Neutral)`
other is `comments_created_at with (Monday, Tuesday, Wed, Thu, Fri, sat, sun)`

I have to put `Overall_sentiment` as dependent variable for regression. I know for 2 level we can use `glm()`.

As there is three levels in dependent variable what should I do.
I ran the model using `glm` function it worked. But I don't know how to interpret the result.

```
m <- glm(as.numeric(Meteor$overall_sentiment) ~ comments_created_at, data = Meteor)
summary(m)
```

OUTPUT

```
Call:
glm(formula = as.numeric(Meteor$overall_sentiment) ~ comments_created_at, 
    data = Meteor)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.3364  -0.3364   0.6636   0.7030   0.7821  

Coefficients:
                        Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)             2.296965   0.011820 194.320  < 2e-16 ***
comments_created_atMon -0.005070   0.017018  -0.298 0.765751    
comments_created_atSat -0.037599   0.021351  -1.761 0.078258 .  
comments_created_atSun -0.079039   0.023320  -3.389 0.000701 ***
comments_created_atThu -0.007945   0.016532  -0.481 0.630832    
comments_created_atTue  0.039464   0.015337   2.573 0.010083 *  
comments_created_atWed  0.005864   0.015871   0.369 0.711762    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 0.6582407)

    Null deviance: 20097  on 30501  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 20073  on 30495  degrees of freedom
AIC: 73814

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 2
```

Comment: You didn't indicate the family of response (binomial), and your model made a linear regression fit. It is a possible way to solve your task, but first of all, you have to manage your response variable so that 1 = negative, 2 = neutral, and 3 = positive (ordinal scale)... What you did may be very different, and results became simply misleading. Also, you don't necessarily need **glm**, you can start off with **lm**.

Answer (score 0):

Your response factor `overall_sentiment` with levels (Positive, Negative, Neutral)` looks like ordinal, so I would start out trying ordinal logistic regression.  [There are many posts on this site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=ordinal+logistic+regression+answers%3A1).

But you used the usual `glm` function, but **without a `family` argument**. That gives you a linear regression model (with assumption about gaussian errors), and you converted the response to numerical!  That gives you nonsensical results, period. **Don't try to interpret that output, start anew**.  **If** you had used the somewhat more sensible `family=binomial` argument, then the following excerpt from the R help page is relevant:

> For binomial and quasibinomial families the response can also
>        be specified as a factor (when the first level denotes failure
>        and all others success)

But neither is that what you want!  For ordinal logistic regression in R, [start with for instance](https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-perform-ordinal-logistic-regression-in-r/)  or  [How do I run Ordinal Logistic Regression analysis in R with both numerical / categorical values?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/93454/how-do-i-run-ordinal-logistic-regression-analysis-in-r-with-both-numerical-cat).